# 3 page navigation issue

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I have a little critical scenario.

Consider 3 pages. **Page1**, **Page2**, **Page3**.

From **Page1**. One parameter come in QueryString named 'note'. It is having two values 'CreateNote' or 'UpdateNote'. On bases of those values, I am hide and show few contents on **Page2**.

Till here no problem.

Now from **Page2** I need to navigate to **Page3**. On **Page3** a back button. I tried to set **note** attribute on Back but still that's not setting these information and hence on **Page2** null pointer accessption arise.

---

**A few code as below**

**Page1** URL like

```
http://localhost:9095/Oscer/pages/UpdateNote.jsf?modified=NO&note=UpdateNote&docid=206&callFrom=prescribe
```

On **Page2**

It's handle using scriptlets like...

Set note object on backingbean constructor call.

```
<%
    String note = request.getParameter("note");
    if(note == null || note.equals("")){
        note = (String)request.getAttribute("note");
    }
    request.setAttribute("note",note);
%>
```

On **Page3**

Tried to handle on BackButton like,

```
if(note == null){
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Map<String,String> requestObj = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
            if(requestObj != null){
                note = requestObj.get("note"); //Either of CreateNote or UpdateNote
            }
        }

        request.setAttribute("note", note);
```

Now when we navigate from **Page3** to **Page2** back though I set `request.setAttribute("note", note);`  It gives NULL pointer exception cause of note on **Page2** not set yet :(

I can't understand how to navigate in case like query string handeled jsp page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it... :)

What I did is...

While going from **Page1** to **Page2** on one of the backingBean let say **sampleBackingBean** set one variable. Initialize it's value by getting **note** from request Scope in default constructor of **SampleBackingBean**.

And on jsp **Page2** Whatever show and hide content is there rendered using **`{sampleBackingBean.note}`**

Now everything is working fine... :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the `note` attribute in request scope, you can keep it in Session scope while navigation from Page1 to Page2. On Page2 retrieve this attribute from session rather than query string (or request scope). So on Page3, even if back button is pressed, you code should work fine.

Comment: You are right but in case out of those 3 page, if user move to any other page from menu. It will be there in session for always...  And to put this kind of value in session is not a good idea...

Comment: In your solution, if you put the value of `note` in request scope, then if on Page3 the user clicks `Back` button, the request scoped `note` variable will not be passed to Page2 and you will get `NullPointerException`